# C++ Visual Studio cannot assign value of type to entity of same type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, enums

I am writing a class called `BleakField`, and it uses an enumeration called `DrawStyle`.
`DrawStyle` is forward declared in the area marked protected (it needs public access but the class has protected members of type DrawStyle) as such:

```
class BleakField {
protected:
    enum DrawStyle;
    DrawStyle type;
```

It is fully defined right after public:

```
public:
    enum DrawStyle : bool {DRAW_SOLID = true, DRAW_TRANSPARENT = false};
```

Inside the constructor for the class, I set "type" to `DRAW_SOLID`.

```
BleakField::BleakField() {
    type = DRAW_SOLID;
```

These are the only areas that deal with this type in the class so far (and the rest of the class is properly defined I just didn't include it because it isn't necessary but I obviously closed the brackets and everything), and I am getting

```
IntelliSense error: a value of type "BleakField::DrawStyle" cannot 
be assigned to an entity of type "BleakField::DrawStyle"
```

I am highly confused as to why I cannot assign values of a type to entities of the same type. I figured it could just be a glitch and I tried deleting and retyping it, but it is still doing this. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can avoid it?

EDIT: It gives me a warning about the change from protected to public, indicating that the protected status gets overwritten by the public one. Also I have done this exact thing before and not gotten that error, which I find odd. And I can definitely forward declare enums, but even moving sections around so that I don't need to didn't solve it. Apparently I can compile the program with half the code unfinished and it worked, but the error is still there. So I guess the compiler thinks it is fine, just not Visual Studio.

Comment: Try compiling it and see if it actually gives you an error. Intellisense is not the compiler.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to forward-declare an `enum`.  Are you?

Comment: Try `enum DrawStyle: bool;` as the forward declaration.

Comment: I thought ISO C++ forbid forward decls for enums. My clang certainly whines about it. And even if C++11 allows it (pretty sure it does) , don't think you can change the access level between the forward and the decl. I think you need to do what @n.m. suggests, but also preclude it with `public:` before you enter your `protected:` section. [See it live](http://ideone.com/m2K0um)

Comment: @Whoz s/preclude/prefix/ (although actually I rather like it as it stands)

Comment: @AlanStokes Lord my vernacular has gone down the crapper in the last 5 years. Must be related to dealing day-in and day-out with my teenage-daughter's friends. Ugh.

Comment: @MMavipc I can't compile it fully without commenting out half the code in the project, but the error isn't going away. Maybe once I finish it will just ignore it.